# Why can't I put a QFrame in a layout?

Tags: qt

I have this architecture :

[image]

But as you can see the sfmlFrame isn't in the "gameRoom" layout.
So When I resize the window the sfmlFrame stay the same, and the `resizeEvent` is never triggered.

XML:

```
<widget class="QWidget" name="gameRoom">
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_4">
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <widget class="QFrame" name="sfmlFrame">
          <property name="frameShape">
           <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="frameShadow">
           <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
```

Have you got an idea why the sfmlFrame can't be put in a layout ?

EDIT : [image]

Comment: Why your layout for game room is Grid? If you need just a frame inside, change the gameRoom layout to Vertical (QVBoxLayout) or Horizontal (doesn't matter for single child).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The frame is inside the layout, the "broken layout" icon in the object tree indicates that the frame itself doesn't have a layout.

Comment: I also tried to add a layout only to the frame, but that's still doesn't working, I still have the broken layout icon.

Comment: How did you "add" the layout? Selecting the frame and pressing one of the layout toolbar buttons?

Comment: I add a new layout to the "gameRoom" page. I cannot add a layout to my frame directly, it's grey tinted. I added a screen.

Comment: You can't layout your frame, cause it has nothing to layout. If you add inside of it for a example a QWidget, you should be able to apply the layout on it.

Comment: @Rinold ah, seems one can only set a layout on an empty container in code. In any case, that would only make the "broken layout" symbol change.

Comment: @DimitriDanilov I see, must have changed in some designer version and is now only possible in code. While strange, it is only a temporary problem, since it will go away once you add children to the frame. At which point the frame will also have a size. suitable for its content